# Snort rule does not alarm

Tags: snort

I have the following rule

```
alert tcp any any <> any any (Msg:"Flooding attack!"; detection_filter:track by_dst, count 50, seconds 10;sid:1000036)
```

The rule works perfectly if no other rules are used, but if there are other rules it has no effect even if packet count is much more that 50 in 10 seconds. Is this a Snort's bug or I don't understand something?

Comment: I think there is a rule that consumes traffic first.

Comment: No, the problem is that Snort doesn't trigger any other alarm at all, just no messages...so I don't think it's problem of rule order(choice between generic on or not)

Comment: Do you know snort mailing list? Maybe you will receive answer more quickly. https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/snort-sigs or https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/snort-users

Comment: You can keyword search on following link. https://sourceforge.net/p/snort/mailman/snort-sigs/ or https://sourceforge.net/p/snort/mailman/snort-users/

Comment: And I guess it is bug, if a result of testing in the same traffic.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try to ask on mailing list.